# How to ask for the same type in Scala generics without introducing a third type parameter?

Tags: scala, generics

Right now my trait has an extra type T which has no real usage other than to ensure `B` and `R` have the same generic type.

`trait GenericBuilder[T <: Any, B <: Builder[T], R <: Result[T]]`

To simplify the declaration, I wonder if there is a way to eliminate `T` in this case while maintaining the type strictness.

**EDIT:** I don't have control of the `Builder` or `Result` code - they are pulled in from some java artifacts outside.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to simplify that part of the declaration you could move the types into members, but then you end up having to cart around more information because you need a witness that the types are the same:

```
trait Builder {
  type T
}
trait Result {
  type T
}
trait GenericBuilder[B <: Builder, R <: Result] {
  val w: B.T =:= R.T
}
```

Comment: I think that ` =.= ` is deprecated.

Comment: I'm not aware of any deprecation. Scalaz === is better, but that only matters if you have one of the use cases that needs it; =:= suffices for the example.

Comment: Is the syntax right? Should there be an "=" after the outer type? Also where should I place the types? If I place them outside the class, I get an error "wrong top statement declaration". Placing them inside the class obviously doesn't do anything. Also Builder is my trait name but the type alias seems to be hiding it?

Comment: Silly mistake, sorry; I meant that your traits should contain types, not that you should declare separate type aliases for them.

Comment: That makes sense but unfortunately I don't have control of the `Builder` or `Result` code - they are pulled in from some java artifacts outside. I don't want to wrap them and use implicit conversions as that will make things way too complicated.